# Receiving an error when querying records for a grid

Tags: sql, razor, datagrid, webmatrix

I am trying to select all records in the table that belong to the user.  I want to use the user's login ID.  Every time I run the application I receive this error:

> Must declare the scalar variable "@48"

Here is the code:

```
var UserId = WebSecurity.GetUserId(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name);
var db = Database.Open("ApplicationServices");
var stQueryString = "SELECT * FROM Assessment WHERE (UserId) = (@48) ORDER BY SubmitDate";
var data = db.Query(selectQueryString, UserId);
var grid = new WebGrid(data);

 <form action="Screening.cshtml">
    <input type="submit" value="New Assessment">
 </form>
 <div id="grid">
          @grid.GetHtml(
                tableStyle: "grid",
                headerStyle: "grid-header",
                alternatingRowStyle: "grid-alternating-row",
                selectedRowStyle: "grid-selected-row",
                rowStyle: "grid-row-style",
                columns: grid.Columns(
                  grid.Column(header:"", format:@<a href="View/@item.Id">View</a>),
                  grid.Column("Name", format:@<text>item.ClientName</text>),
                  grid.Column("Date", format:@<text>item.SubmitDate</text>)))            
 </div>
```

Comment: is `48` the `userid`? if so you should use `WHERE UserId = 48`

Comment: If UserId truly is "@48" it should be enclosed with quotes, as I just did. OTOH, if that signifies a query parameter incongruously named "48", then it needs to be assigned the actual value.

Comment: The UserId is not "@48".  "@48" is the column position.  I thought you are supposed to use column positions when using Razor.

Comment: It's working now.  Thanks B. Clay Shannon 22!